# create table programmatically without using ddl-auto = update in application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to create table programmatically (After check a table is exist then create table based on Entity) without using ddl-auto = update in application. Properties. I am using Spring Boot: 3 and Hibernate: 6
I try with Schema Export which is shows errors as it is deprecated. Most of the solution I found which is deprecated.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

I want to create table from my existing Entity by programmatically. I want to check by certain table exists or not.If not then I want to create table from my Entity. I put a github link where I try several way.

https://github.com/MohosinMiah/dynamic-table-creation-using-spring-boot/blob/main/src/main/java/com/dynamictable/dynamictable/controller/HomeController.java?fbclid=IwAR1CGfb8MvZpNZjX-w4EGVB1qAj4IuQgrXSQ1N34tDIDxJT8pfojgGLgM7Q

Comment: To what purpose exactly? What database are you targeting, and how are you generating the DDL from your Entity? It doesn't seem overly useful if you are going to have a single, static PaymentMethod entity class to bother with lazily/dynamically checking and creating that table - why not just do it upfront on deployment as JPA is designed for, and avoid the risks. Otherwise, if this is just the first POC of a more dynamic solution, you might look for dynamic entity options like (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic ).

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris . Actually I want to create database sharding daily basic. So, I want to create table from Entity dynamically. Thank you. Would you suggest me any other approach. Thank you